# SQL query performance: Running multiple instances of same query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

First scenario: I run a query in one instance in SQL server.
Second scenario: I run the same query in two instances, i.e., running the same script but in two instances.

Assume that both queries start with the cache clean.  Will the second scenario take longer to complete?

Basically my question is whether using the database in two instances results in slower performance than using the database in only one instance.

Thanks!

Comment: If the two instances of SQL Server are running on the same machine, then they might be competing for physical resources.  So, yes, running on both instances could result in slower performance.

Comment: Clarification: by "two instances", do you mean "two independent SQL servers serving two independent clients", or do you mean "two independent clients accessing the same single server" ?  That will drastically change your answer.

Comment: There are many caches: disk level, controller level, OS level, SQL Server level.  Different SQL Server instances only share the first three.  If your most important cache is the fourth one, you'll notice an impact.

Comment: I mean two independent clients accessing the same single server.  I am basically running the same script two times at the same time, within the same SQL Server application if that makes sense.  I open the script twice within the same application and run them both.